# [FireDAC][Phys][Ora]-314. Cannot load vendor library [/usr/lib/ems/libclntsh.so] - Delphi RAD Server on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, oracle, delphi, firedac

After installing Delphi 10.3.1 RAD Server (EMS modules) in Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS  , I deployed and tested a simple (with no database access) Delphi RAD Server application and it worked fine. 
When deploying an application with one Resource that access an Oracle Database in a remote server I got the following message :

> [FireDAC][Phys][Ora]-314. Cannot load vendor library [libclntsh.so].
>   Hint: check it is in the PATH or application EXE directories, and has
>   x64 bitness.

Oracle instant client 64bits was installed following the document :

> https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html

all installation steps were accomplished accordingly.

After that I could  deploy a Delphi console application accessing the remote database with no trouble.

The major difference between this console application and the RAD Server module is that, in this last I created the database access components at runtime (TFDManager , TFDConnection, TFDPhysOracleDriverLink) while in the first I used a datamodule with design-time components placed on it. All properties values are the same.

The path   **/usr/lib/ems** and the file **libclntsh.so** exist and have proper access rights for execution.

I've tried several different configurations on Delphi data access components  but no success for now !

Thanks !

Comment: Are you sure that you have installed the 64bits client and not a 32bits client ?. The error message asks you to check it.

Comment: @Marc, yes I'm sure. It is Oracle instant client  11.2.0.4 got from the link http://download.oracle.com/otn/linux/instantclient/11204/instantclient-basic-linux.x64-11.2.0.4.0.zip

Comment: Can you try a third-party tool (an Oracle administrator, for exemple) to confirm if the problem is with the Delphi/FireDAC part or the Oracle Client part ?.

Comment: @Marc, from this Linux machine I can use SQLPlus to access the remote database and I also could run a Delphi console application to access the database. As far as I understood, this console application uses the same Oracle instant client driver to reach the database. Therefore, this server can access remote database , BUT RAD Server database application deployed on that, can not !

Comment: That's odd, have you checked that the $PATH variable contains the /usr/lib/ems directory ?. echo $PATH

Comment: @Marc, yes  I checked  PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH , they are included startup/boot related files (.profile, bash).

Comment: 1) Do you run EMSDevServer or EMS/Apache ?
2) Remove TFDManager from the list of dynamically created components
3) Try to specify in TFDPhysOracleDriverLink.VendorLib full path to libclntsh.so.
Anything helps ?

Comment: @da-soft, I run under Apache, but if I use EMSDevServer  the problem remanis the same.  I had already removed TFDManager and configured connection under TFDConnection properties, it does not work , same error!

Comment: @da-soft, I also place the full path in the TFDPhysOracleDriverLink.VendorLib , as /usr/lib/ems/libclntsh.so , but , does not work either. It seems that RAD Server/Apache is not recognizing  it as a driver or can not reach the file in the location !

Comment: Dear all , I SOLVED the issue , based on support of Embarcadero team, I did the following :  

Installed Oracle Instant Client 12.2,  I used dynamic library cache with ldconfig, instead of using LD_LIBRARY_PATH 
1. Create a file in /etc/ld.so.conf.d/, for example called oracle.conf.
2. Add the directory containing libclntsh.so
3. Save the file and run sudo ldconfig to update the dynamic library cache.

I removed references of library from LD_LIBRARY_PATH in .profile .
Finally I could run my RAD Server package accessing a remote database. Thanks to all that contributed  !